# Questions related to the calibration of a VNA?

Tags: rf

I am seeking answers to these two questions related to the calibration of the VNA.

(1) What type of VNA calibration is required to measure the reflection, transmission, and phase of an attenuator?

*[My Answer] Full **two**-port calibration, that is, TOSM type utilizing a calibration kit: "through", "Open", "Short", and "Match". Am I thinking right?*

(2) Now instead of an attenuator, I have a termination. Then, what type of calibration would I need to measure reflection and phase?

*[My Answer] **one**-port calibration, like, OSM type utilizing a calibration kit: "Open", "Short", and "Match". Am I thinking right?*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You need T (through) when you want to know transmission/scattering parameter S12. This is independent of „phase“, because VNA will give you Sxy scattering parameters which include phase information.

Comment: In addition to "Thru" you will also have twice as many Open, Short, and Match measurements to make when calibrating for a 2-port measurement relative to a 1-port measurement.

Answer (score 3):

What calibration you "need" depends very much on how accurate you need your measurement to be and how bad are the internal errors in your VNA set.

What I learned to call SOLT (short/open/load/thru) calibration is certainly a good choice for 2-port calibration on many VNAs (historically this calibration was mainly used on "dual 6-port" VNAs, but I suspect VNA technology has advanced since I learned this stuff).

But if you have modest accuracy requirements, or if your VNA doesn't support a full 2-port calibration (some lower-cost models don't), you might get away with a simpler (less time-consuming) calibration using fewer measurements, perhaps only a thru response measurement.

Or if you are working in a transmission line technology like microstrip where it's not feasible to produce a very good Short or Open standard, you might want to use something like the TRL (Thru/Reflect/Line) calibration.